# How to create a networkDynamic object in R from a list of networks

Tags: r, dynamic, graph, igraph

I've been trying to do some dynamic network analysis, and I've found that the R language packages may come handy in that, so I tried to use it but I've faced a lot of difficulties:

- I have edges files that I've downloaded from networkrepository.com which contains edges and their weight. all the files represent the state of the graph each day.
  example of the files:
  1 2 44
  1 3 56
  1 6 34
  2 3 56
  2 7 65
- I managed to put each of the files in a graph with the package igraph and the convert it to a network unsing the function asNetwok from the package intergraph, but it seems like I lose the weight, so is there any way I can put it back on the network.
- Finally I tried to put all the networks in a single Dynamic Network using the function networkDynamic from the package networkDynamic, but it returns an error about the vertices.pid so I want to know if there's any way to put the vertices names in the edges files as the pid required

```
library(igraph)
path <- '../Ants'
files <- list.files(path=path)
library(comprehenr)
nl <- to_list(for (i in files) read.table(paste0(path,"/",i), col.names = c("V1", "V2", "weight"), sep=" "))
netlist <- to_list(for (df in nl) graph_from_data_frame(df, directed = FALSE))
is_weight <- to_list(for (g in netlist) is_weighted(g))
direc <- to_list(for (g in netlist) is_directed(g))
library(network)
netlist <- to_list(for (g in netlist) asNetwork(g, attrmap=attrmap()))
library(networkDynamic)
dn <- networkDynamic(network.list=netlist, create.TEAs = T)
```